# Find all of the possible solutions of $250x+111y=7$, where both $x$ and $y$ are integers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, euclidean-algorithm

This is my steps

```
1 = 28-1x27

  = 28-1x(111-3x28)

  = 4x28-1x111

  = 4x(250-2x111)-1x111

  = 4x250-9x111

x7=> 7 = 28x250-63x111
```

Then I don’t know why the next step is this

$ = 250(28-111k) + 111(-63+250k) , \forall k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer:

$x = 28-111k, y = -63+250k$.

Comment: Hint: suppose $(x',y')$ is another solution, then $250(x'-28)+111(y'+63)=0$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You should try to view your equation as $250x\equiv 7\pmod{111}$. From your working we have $4\cdot 250\equiv 1\pmod{111}$ and hence one strategy is to multiply the equation by $4$ and get $x\equiv 28\pmod{111}$.

Comment: Essentially it is same as solving $ax=b$ with $a=250,b=7$ as $x=b(1/a)$ but doing all operations modulo $111$ and in particular we need to find reciprocal of $a=250$ also modulo $111$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have shown that $(x,y)=(28,-63)$ is a solution to
$$250x+111y=7.$$
If $(x,y)=(m,n)$ is another solution to this equation, then
$$250(28-m)+111(-63-n)=0,$$
or equivalently
$$250(28-m)=111(63+n).$$
By unique factorization of integers, and because $250$ and $111$ are coprime, it follows that $28-m$ is a multiple of $111$ and that $-63-n$ is a multiple $250$. So for some integer $k$ we have
$$28-m=111k\qquad\text{ and }\qquad 63+n=250k.$$
Equivalently, we see that
$$(m,n)=(28-111k,-63+250k),$$
for some integer $k$. It is then easy to verify that *every* integer $k$ yields a solution.

Comment: Shouldn't you have written $250(28-m) = 111(63+n)$?

Comment: @EverywhereDense You are right, I have corrected it now.

Comment: Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

$$x=250^{-1} \cdot 7=28^{-1} \cdot 7=4^{-1} \cdot 1=112^{-1} \cdot 28=$$
$$=1^{-1} \cdot 28=1\cdot 28=28 \left(\mod {111} \right).$$

$$x=111n+28$$

$$250 \left( 111n+28 \right)+111y=7<=>...$$